# Vue.js Dropdown Component Cut-off Inside a Scrollable Container

Tags: html, css, vuejs3, vue-component, overflow

I'm making a text editor similar to Notion. Every page in page-list has a dropdown component for additional actions. To accommodate cases with more items than can be displayed on the screen, I've placed the page-list inside a scrollable container. This, however, causes the dropdown to be cut off by the container's bounds. ChatGPT told me I should be using vue Teleport component to move the dropdown out of the scrollable block but I could'n integrate it successfully. I wonder if there is also a easier solution.

[Preview of how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKEJa.png)

In my `EditorLayout.vue` I defined a slot for page-list and apply the over-flow-scroll:

```js
<div class="max-h-96 overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden">
    <slot name="page-list" />
</div>
```

Within `page-list`, I iterate over page components (`Page.vue`), each of which may contain a dropdown menu (`DropDown.vue`). Here's a simplidied version if what my `Page.vue` looks like:

```js
<a class="cursor-pointer relative group flex justify-between items-center px-3 py-1 min-h-8 rounded-md font-semibold text-md text-white hover:bg-blue-600 transition"
       :class="{'selected-item': selected === page.id}"
       :title="page.name">
        
        <div class="flex items-center gap-1 flex-grow truncate">
            <!-- Chevron and Page Name -->
        </div>

        <div class="ml-1 hidden group-hover:flex gap-1 items-center">
            <Dropdown align="left" width="48">
                <template #trigger>
                <!-- Dropdown Trigger and Content -->
                </template>
            </Dropdown>
            <template #content>
            <!-- Additional icons/buttons -->
            </template>
        </div>
    </a>
```

And the `Dropdown.vue` component:

```js
<template>
    <div class="relative">
        <div @click="open = !open">
            <slot name="trigger" />
        </div>

        <!-- Full Screen Dropdown Overlay -->
        <div v-show="open" class="fixed inset-0 z-40" @click="open = false"></div>

        <Transition
            enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-200"
            enter-from-class="opacity-0 scale-95"
            enter-to-class="opacity-100 scale-100"
            leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75"
            leave-from-class="opacity-100 scale-100"
            leave-to-class="opacity-0 scale-95"
        >
            <div
                v-show="open"
                class="absolute z-50 mt-2 rounded-md shadow-lg ltr:origin-top-left rtl:origin-top-right start-0 w-48"
                style="display: none"
                @click="open = false"
            >
                <div class="rounded-md ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5" :class="contentClasses">
                    <slot name="content" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </Transition>
    </div>
</template>
```

How can I ensure the dropdown is fully visible and not cut off by the scrollable container? Any advice on using Teleport or another approach would be greatly appreciated.